# kohana 3.3 routing with virtual directory seem not to be working

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana-3

I can't figure it out, im running kohana in virtual directory

here's my virtual host setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/dtr
ServerName local.dtr.com
</VirtualHost>
```

here's my bootstrap setup

```
Kohana::init(array(
'base_url'   => '/',
'index_file' => FALSE,
));
```

and here's my .htaccess setup

```
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /
```

now if i access this URL `http:// local.dtr.com` I can get my default page

but when i try to do like this `http:// local.dtr.com/welcome`    <-- welocme is name of my controller

i got an error 404

but when i try this way `http:// local.dtr.com/index.php/welcome`  it works

but when i try my other action from my controller like `http://local.dtr.com/index.php/welcome/test` -- it keeps accessing the default action which is index.

Please help it's driving me nuts. :-(

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: yes, i think it's kohana 3.3 issue, im not sure, but i just use 3.2 and it's working fine.